# (Lotus Notes)Can the labels in the form set display conditions?

Tags: label, lotus-notes, hcl-notes

There is currently a form, suppose there are two labels, I want to have a field with a value for the label ex2 to appear, if not, hide the label ex2.

Is there a place to set it?

[image]

---

After I tried, the tab still visible...

In the Designer :

[image]

In the Client :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide a TAB you simply hide its contents. If you e.g. would want to hide ex2 you would select the complete content of the tab", open the text properties (Alt + Enter) and enter something like:

```
HideEx2 = "Yes"
```

in the hide- when formula. Then the tab will disappear as soon as the field "HideEx2" gets the value "Yes".
Take care: Hide whens are NOT calculated "automatically". If your Hide- When depends on the value of an option or checkbox field you need to check the mark "Refresh fields on keyword change" in the field properties of the HideEx2- field.
Otherwise your user needs to press F5 or save the document to make the tab appear / disappear

[image]

If there are Tables in the tab, then you need to do three steps:

1. select everything before the table (red BEFORE in the screenshot), set the hide- when
2. select all cells of the table, set the hide when
3. and at last select the text after the table (red AFTER in the screenshot) and hide it.

3 different selections, 3 times setting the checkmark, 3 times inserting the hide when! You CAN'T do it in one step, it's not possible to select a table AND its surronding and set the hide when for everything at once. You can select it, but hide when will only be set for some of the stuff.

If there is one single line that is not hidden in the tab, then it will be visible.

Comment: I edited my question after I used your advice, but the tab still visible.

Comment: See my edit: Write Some text BEFORE the inner table like "BEFORE", make it red. Then write some text after the table like "AFTER" and also make it red. Now open your form: If your hide-whens are correct, then the tab is hidden. If it shows "BEFORE" in red, then you know you need to fix the hide when of that text, it it shows "AFTER", then you need to fix that. In case of Table in Table you need to set the hide when in 3 different places as described in my post.

Comment: @Ariel Please accept the answer as the correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers